# What are the core differences between Airodump-ng, Wireshark, and TCPdump?

Tags: network, wireshark, sniffer, monitoring, airodump-ng

As all three tools are packet sniffers, I would have expected them to give me the same results when I use them to monitor my home's network, but they don't. Therefore what are the core differences and which one is the best to use?

Comment: How do you mean "different results" between Wireshark and TCPdump output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airdump-ng is for capturing 802.11 frames, so you use this tool exclusively for wireless networks.

Wireshark and TCPdump are similar but Wireshark is more complex, also has a GUI. E.g. you can set many filters and perform more advanced analysis. TCPdump is more lightweight.

Which one is best to use is a broad question and is up to you, depending on what you need. You don't have to limit yourself to one if you think you need several different sniffers.

Comment: More specifically - `airodump-ng` (sic) is 802.11-specific in that it allows for controlling the current radio channel of the monitoring wlan-device, plus "scanning" by switching across multiple channels. `tcpdump` has no such concept and requires using some separate tool to set the channel first before capturing. Wireshark has some build-in UI support for controlling a USB capture device but again it is much more heavyweight.